# FatalExecutionEngineError was detected. in Simple .net application

Tags: c#, .net

Visual Studio 10 was working well on Windows 7. Recently I upgraded to Windows 10. That day onwards my .NET programs are not working. Even if I write a simple console application, it also throws an error.

This is the exception:

> The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error
>   was at 0x69e3b015, on thread 0x17a4. The error code is 0xc0000005.
>   This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable
>   portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user
>   marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the
>   stack.

This is my code.

```
using System;

namespace NeoTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hi");                   
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try reinstalling .Net?

Comment: Reinstalled, same result.